# How to not apply [routerLink] on a child element?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I want to make a child element to trigger it own click even , and don't respond to it parent element having [routerLink], **the problem is** the child element can't run it `delete()` function in `(click)="delete()"` it just follow it parent in `[routerLink]` (it navigate to /product/:id)

```
    <div class="item">

<!-- parent element -->
    <a [routerLink]="['/product/'+product.id]">
        <div class="figure">
          <div class="sides">
            <div class="side">
              <div class="card">
<img class="img" [src]="product.thumb"> 
                <div class="content">
                  <div class="header">{{product.name}}</div>
                  <div class="meta"> <span>product.category</span> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="extraContent"> <span class="ui right floated black">

                <!-- child element -->
                <a (click)="delete()" ><i class="red trash outline icon"></i></a></span> <span><i class="deleteProductIcon"></i></span> </div> 
                <!-- child element -->

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
<!-- parent element -->

</div>
```

I tried to move `[routerLink]` to an upper `div` but it still doing  the same behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you stopPropgation in the delete function() the event won't bubble up to the anchor tag with the routerLink

```
// pass in the event object to the delete function
<a (click)="delete($event)" ><i class="red trash outline icon"></i></a>

// in the delete function, stop event propagation
delete(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: i tried this :   
`
delete(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('deleted');
  }
`
     and the alert() worked fine , but after this it still navigating to to /product/:id

Comment: @FlashCode can you switch up your DOM? Does everything in the parent element need to be wrapped in the routerlink? It seems kind of odd that clicking on anything in that element (other than the delete icon) would navigate to a new page. I would expect there to be a delete icon & a separate navigation icon

Comment: yeah you're right i should find a way to not wrap the delete icon and keep the others

Comment: it works ! i just moved [routerLink] to the upper div , thanks !

Answer (score 4):

In your case the child just specifying stopPropagation might not work sometimes. Specially when child and parent both have their separate "routerLinks" defined

I suggest handling the routing using "navigate" method in component and returning "false" in the end. This would prevent parent route to trigger after completion of click handler of child.

```
// pass in the event object to the delete function
<a (click)="delete($event)" ><i class="red trash outline icon"></i></a>

// in the delete function, stop event propagation
delete(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.route.navigate(['child/route/here']);
    return false;
}
```

returning false from click handler prevented the parent route to work for me.

Comment: Thank you - The crucial bit was "returning false in the click event handler. This fixed my problem (Click event in a child element, where parent element had an anchor with routerlink), and should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

the `event.stopPropagation();` only, did not work for me. All I had to do was drop in `e.preventDefault();` too

```
// In your HTML   
<a [routerLink]="['/product/'+product.id]">
     <!-- your other inner stuff -->
     <a (click)="delete($event)" ><i class="red trash outline icon"></i></a>
</a>

// In your component
delete(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```