# Not work Every time click event[angular 2]

Tags: angular

i have problem with click event.

I have array of object:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  title:"Title 1",
  name: "Name 1",
  hit:true
 },
{
  id: 2,
  title:"Title 2",
  name: "Name 2",
  hit:true
},
..
]
```

i display this in ngFor loop

```
 <article class="container">
   <custom-item *ngFor="let deal of deals" [deal]="deal" ></custom-item>
 </article>
```

inside custom-item i have:

```
 <section class="{{getSectionClass()}}">
   <header>
    <div class="icon">
        <i class="wdIcon {{getIconClass()}}"></i>
        <span class="points"> {{deal.points}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="hit" *ngIf="deal.hit && !checkIsEnded()">HIT</div>
    <div class="pointOptions" *ngIf="!checkIsEnded()">
        <button md-mini-fab class="minus" (click)="minus()"><span>-</span></button>
        <button md-mini-fab class="plus" (click)="plus()"><span>+</span></button>
    </div>
  </header>
  ...
 </section>
```

problem is in :

```
      <button md-mini-fab class="minus" (click)="minus()"><span>-</span></button>
      <button md-mini-fab class="plus" (click)="plus()"><span>+</span></button>
```

for array about 20 items, this event not fired for about 3-4 time. Clicking nothing calls.

in component:

```
minus() {
    console.log("minus");
}
plus () {
    console.log("plus");
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to [stop event Propagation ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44726816/how-to-not-apply-routerlink-on-a-child-element/44726868#44726868)

Comment: nothing stands out, could something about the md-mini-fab attribute on the buttons be blocking the click?

Comment: Yes, this md-mini-fab made a problem. When i removed it, it worked. thx.